# Whats wrong with this SQLCe Query?

Tags: .net, ado.net, sql-server-ce

in the past hour i have been trying different variants of this query but i get error at the username   , and the username is just a normal string with username that i get from xml file containing no special characters or whatsoever

I'm using SLQ compact 3.5

P.S i tried to use ? instead of @username also not working
all feilds are "nchar" except "date"

```
                C = nodeItem["user_from"].InnerText;
                avatar = nodeItem["user_from_avatar"].InnerText;
                string msgText = nodeItem["message"].InnerText;
                DateTime dt=DateTime.Now;

                string sql = "INSERT INTO posts(user,msg,avatar,date) VALUES(@username,@messige,@userpic,@thedate)";
                using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",C);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@messige", msgText.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userpic", avatar.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@thedate", dt);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    adapter.Update(data);
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

The error msg :  [image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m11962/1247582804-clip-16kb.png))</sub>
Thanks , 
Nikola

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try surrounding 'user' with square brackets, '[user]'  (and possibly date).

Answer (score 1):

In SqlCe u cannot use directly the parameters I mean the sentence:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO posts(user,msg,avatar,date) VALUES(@username,@messige,@userpic,@thedate)";
```

is wrong. it should be

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO posts(user,msg,avatar,date) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
```

and then followed by:

```
using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, connection))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",C);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@messige", msgText.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@userpic", avatar.ToString());
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@thedate", dt);
                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    adapter.Update(data);
                    connection.Close();
                }
```

In SqlCe the parameters are passed as "?"

Hope it helps you